# Closing the figure window causes a new figure window to open

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

This is a analog clock. It runs perfectly. But once I close the clock, another figure opens up, and only the clock hands show. This makes it difficult to stop the program. How can I stop the program?

```matlab
x=0;y=0;r=10;
hold on;
theta = 0:pi/60:2*pi;
xc = r * cos(theta);
yc = r * sin(theta);
h = plot(xc,yc,'r','linewidth',4);
axis off
r=9; i=1;
set(gca,'FontWeight','bold');

for theta = pi/6: pi/6: 2*pi
    y1 = r * cos(theta);
    x1 = r * sin(theta);
    plot([x1/9*8 x1/9*7],[y1/9*8 y1/9*7],'color',[0 0 1])
    text(x1/9*9.5,y1/9*9.5,num2str(i),'color',[0 0 1]);
    i=i+1;
end

for theta=pi/30 : pi/30 : 2*pi
    y1 = 10 * cos(theta);
    x1 = 10 * sin(theta);
    plot([x1/9*8 x1/9*7],[y1/9*8 y1/9*7],'color',[0 0 0])
end

while(1)
    tic
    c = clock;
    c = c(1,4:6);
    minute =c(1,2); sec=c(1,3);
    if (c(1,1)>12)
       hr = c(1,1)-12;
    else
       hr = c(1,1);
    end
    min1 = ceil(minute/12);
    theta = (hr*pi)/6 + (min1*pi)/30;
    f=figure(1); hold on;
    y1 = 3 * cos(theta); Yhr = [0 y1];
    x1 = 3 * sin(theta); Xhr = [0 x1];
    hrhnd=plot(Xhr,Yhr);hold on;
    theta1 = (minute*pi)/30;
    y2 = 4.5 * cos(theta1); Ymin = [0 y2];
    x2 = 4.5 * sin(theta1); Xmin = [0 x2];
    minhnd=plot(Xmin,Ymin);
    theta2 = (sec*pi)/30;
    y3 = 5 * cos(theta2); Ysec = [0 y3];
    x3 = 5 * sin(theta2); Xsec = [0 x3];
    sechnd=plot(Xsec,Ysec);
    z=toc;
    pause(1-z);
     delete(sechnd);
     delete(minhnd);
     delete(hrhnd);
end
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: for it to show the real time. which it does. but when i close the clock animation. other weird animation pop up

Comment: can you run it and see if it does the same for you

Comment: You only describe the actual behavior but it's unclear for me what you want to change? What is the expected behavior? No, I can't run the code.

Comment: i am getting the expected behavior. but its doing more then whats expected

Comment: What is it doing more?

Comment: once i close the expected file. other files open up. its hard to explain. i wish you could run it

Comment: What other files?

Comment: it will open up a figure but its clock hands moving but no clock. those are not supposed to run again once i have closed the original figure

Comment: Instead of closing the figure, press Ctrl+C, which will stop the running script. You can then close the window. If you need to be able to stop the loop by closing the window, add a callback to the window.

Comment: oh wow that actually works. how would you add a callback to the window?

Comment: Note that "file" is not the same as "figure window". Using the right terminology will make it a lot easier to communicate with others.

Comment: Your loop doesn't stop when close a figure. First you're creating a figure and drawing the clock with the two for loops. Then you're moving the hands in the while loop. When you close the figure and the while loop comes to a line like `sechnd=plot(Xsec,Ysec)` it opens a new figure and draws the line.

Comment: @ThomasSablik can you show me how you would format that. can you edit my code into that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to stop the script when you close the window is to have the script test inside its loop if the window still exists.

We start the script by creating a figure window and recording its handle:

```matlab
fig = figure;
```

Next, in the loop, we check to see if the window still exists using `ishandle`:

```matlab
while(ishandle(fig))
   ...
end
```

---

The full program:

```matlab
x=0;y=0;r=10;
fig = figure;       %!!! NEW LINE
hold on;
theta = 0:pi/60:2*pi;
xc = r * cos(theta);
yc = r * sin(theta);
h = plot(xc,yc,'r','linewidth',4);
axis off
r=9; i=1;
set(gca,'FontWeight','bold');

for theta = pi/6: pi/6: 2*pi
    y1 = r * cos(theta);
    x1 = r * sin(theta);
    plot([x1/9*8 x1/9*7],[y1/9*8 y1/9*7],'color',[0 0 1])
    text(x1/9*9.5,y1/9*9.5,num2str(i),'color',[0 0 1]);
    i=i+1;
end

for theta=pi/30 : pi/30 : 2*pi
    y1 = 10 * cos(theta);
    x1 = 10 * sin(theta);
    plot([x1/9*8 x1/9*7],[y1/9*8 y1/9*7],'color',[0 0 0])
end

while(ishandle(fig))    %!!! UPDATED LINE
    tic
    c = clock;
    c = c(1,4:6);
    minute =c(1,2); sec=c(1,3);
    if (c(1,1)>12)
       hr = c(1,1)-12;
    else
       hr = c(1,1);
    end
    min1 = ceil(minute/12);
    theta = (hr*pi)/6 + (min1*pi)/30;
    f=figure(1); hold on;
    y1 = 3 * cos(theta); Yhr = [0 y1];
    x1 = 3 * sin(theta); Xhr = [0 x1];
    hrhnd=plot(Xhr,Yhr);hold on;
    theta1 = (minute*pi)/30;
    y2 = 4.5 * cos(theta1); Ymin = [0 y2];
    x2 = 4.5 * sin(theta1); Xmin = [0 x2];
    minhnd=plot(Xmin,Ymin);
    theta2 = (sec*pi)/30;
    y3 = 5 * cos(theta2); Ysec = [0 y3];
    x3 = 5 * sin(theta2); Xsec = [0 x3];
    sechnd=plot(Xsec,Ysec);
    z=toc;
    pause(1-z);
     delete(sechnd);
     delete(minhnd);
     delete(hrhnd);
end
```

---

You could improve your program by not deleting and re-drawing the hands, but updating their position. You'd do `hrhnd=plot(Xhr,Yhr);` before the loop, to draw the hand in its initial position, and then `set(hrhnd,'XData',Xhr,'YData', Yhr)` to update its position.

You could also do `axis equal` after drawing the clock face, to ensure it is round.

Note that you only need to give `hold on` once at the top, it is not needed after every `plot` command.

Comment: @Jason: Also, if you only _update_ the hands position as Chris suggested (instead of re-drawing), the hands won't change color at each update.